# Horizontal joist losing support from vertical support joist in Garage ceiling?

Tags: garage, joists, construction

It’s happening in few more places which causing horizontal joist turning into little curve.
What mending brace plate should I use?

[image]

Comment: Pictures will help.  Curving joists might  be a good sign that you need more than just mending plates.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to attach. Just added

Comment: It looks like just flat plates will work.  Those joists are usually not for weight loading, more to hold the walls together.  Depending on what is above them, some stuff might need to be moved or spread around more.

Comment: Most likely the plywood and anything on the plywood were not included in the design, and are over-stressing the *rafter ties that are not really joists.*

Comment: Are those struts commonly fastened off-plane?